# Merging multiple Word Docs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to develop a simple code which combines multiple small docx(or rtf) into one docx.

document creation should be based on the following:
1. I have in column A a list of names of the small docs
2. in Column B is one of 2 entries (yes/no)
   ex:

```
    A     B
   doc1  yes      
   doc2  no    
   doc3  yes    
   doc4  yes     
   doc5  no
```

3. I have already supplied the location of the small docs in a cell in the  sheet
4. also supplied the place where the new (merged) doc would be placed

below is a sample of the code

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strRandom = Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, ":", ""), "/", ""), " ", "")
MergeFileName = "Merger" & strRandom & ".doc"
MergeFolder = mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("L10").Value

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
'objSelection.TypeText ("Saving this file after this text")
objDoc.SaveAs (MergeFolder & MergeFileName)

For i = 1 To NoOfFiles
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set tempDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value)
        'Set wb = Documents.Open(MyPath & "\" & MyName)
        Set objTempSelection = objTempWord.Selection
        'objTempSelection.WholeStory
        'Selection.Copy
        tempDoc.Range.Select
        tempDoc.Range.Copy
        'Windows(1).Activate
        'Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        'objSelection.TypeParagraph
        objSelection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
        .InsertBreak wdPageBreak
        tempDoc.Close
    End If
Next

objDoc.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate
MsgBox "Completed...Merge File is saved at " & MergeFolder & MergeFileName
FetchFileClicked = False
End Sub
```

the problem with this code is that it never kills the temp doc opened, so I have 10 docs to be merged I'll end up with 10 WINWORD process and no MSWord windows.
is there a way to fix that problem.
I have heard that if I convert all small docs to .rtf I can parse the file without the need to open it.

Comment: Each time through your loop you are creating a Word Application which you call `objTempWord`.  You never `Quit` it (which is why you end up with 10 WINWORD processes), and you only seem to use it to create an object called `objTempSelection` which you never use.  Perhaps get rid of the superfluous code and your problems will go away.  (As far as I know, there is no need to have multiple Word.Applications running.)

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, you have a list of documents and you want to insert them all into one file.  I have done this with the Selection.InsertFile function, where you define the locations of the files, using CreateObject (Word.Application.Documents.Add) which merges the files into the newly opened Word file.  This would clearly define Word is used, and not WinWord.  If this sounds like something that would work, I could try to add some code in a response.

Comment: @YowE3K: if I introduce quit in the process it would never open up the next doc in the list to copy the content of it unless I m missing smth.

Comment: @Cyril: I don't know why but that is the case, if I check on the processes, I find myself with x number of WINWORD processes = to the number of files merged.

Comment: You don't need `objTempWord`.  Remove the line where you `Set` it and remove the line where you `Set objTempSelection`.  Then you won't need to `Quit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some serious troubleshooting I finally got it to work, and here the code below.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
strRandom = Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, ":", ""), "/", ""), " ", "")
MergeFileName = "Merger" & strRandom & ".doc"
MergeFolder = mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("L10").Value

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

objWord.Visible = True

Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objDoc.SaveAs (MergeFolder & MergeFileName)

For i = 1 To NoOfFiles
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        myName = (Folderpath & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value)

        With appWord.Selection
        .InsertFile Filename:=myName
        End With

        With objWord.Selection
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertBreak Type:=7
        End With
    End If
Next

objDoc.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate
MsgBox "Completed...Merge File is saved at " & MergeFolder & MergeFileName
```

PS: thanks Cyril for the tip it was the key to resolve that pain of mine

Answer (score 0):

I am pulling this code from a userform I use to populate documents from a collection of templates, so my apologies if this doesn't work exactly as I will describe:

```
Sub Insert_File_From_Location()

CreateObject (Word.Application.Documents.Add)

If ComboBox1.Value = "blah" Then
        Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\blah.docx"
    Else:
    End If

End Sub
```

I took out all of the else if statements to make it look simpler.

A possibility is, taking the above code and manipulating to let your Column B cells define the ComboBox1.Value (yes/no entries).  You then would have the Selection.InsertFile FileName:= direct to the location defined in the adjacent cell in Column A.  This would need to be a dynamic reference utilizing a loop through the last row.

What I don't have going on is auto-saving the merged document because I have to, typically, manipulate the contents and remove sections that are standard for some templates in my collection.

Hopefully that helps, Karim!  When working with just Word docs (.doc or .docx) I do have processes show up in my task manager, but they go away when the insert is completed, leaving me with one Word process for the opened document.

Comment: I m sorry but I still new to VBA, if I did what you have asked for in the above section I get an error (runtime error object required) just as I hit the line where I defined the CreateObject (Word.Application>Documents.Add)

Comment: You have a ">" where there should be a "." in the CreateObject.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s try something like combining multiple Word documents; you need to copy all the contents of each one, and paste everything into one consolidated Word doc.  That could take a very long time, especially if there are many files in the folder.  Simply run the script below and the code will do all the work for you.

```
Sub MergeAllWordDocs1()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MyName As String, MyPath As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Documents.Add
    MyPath = "C:\Users\your_path_here\" ' <= change this as necessary
    MyName = Dir$(MyPath & "*.do*") ' not *.* if you just want doc files
    Do While MyName <> ""
        If InStr(MyName, "~") = 0 Then
            Selection.InsertFile _
    FileName:="""" & MyPath & MyName & """",
            ConfirmConversions:=False, Link:=False,
            Attachment:=False
    Selection.InsertBreak Type:=wdPageBreak
  End If
        MyName = Dir() ' gets the next doc file in the directory
    Loop
End Sub
```